# Value attribute keeps getting set to "submit" for one of my input elements

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs

I have 6 input elements and for some reason the `value` attribute of the second one keep defaulting to "Submit". No idea why, it's the only that does it:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.formValues.multiField && this.state.formValues.supplier == "Shell") {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <fieldset>
          <legend><span class="number">1</span> Enter Report</legend>
          <Card Obj={this.state.formValues} />
          <label for="modifier">Modifier:</label>
          <input type="text" id="BC" value={this.value} name="altModifierShell" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
          <input type="text" id="AB" value={this.value} name="altModifierShell" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
          <input type="text" id="SK" value={this.value} name="altModifierShell" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
          <input type="text" id="MB" value={this.value} name="altModifierShell" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
          <input type="text" id="ON" value={this.value} name="altModifierShell" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
          <input type="text" id="QC" value={this.value} name="altModifierShell" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I wrapped tried wrapping all the input tags in `<li>` tags and that fixed it, but I'd rather not have to use them.

edit: Here's what it looks like

[image: issue screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a running example showing this issue?

Comment: I included a screenshot if that helps?

Comment: it could be the browser doing that, have you tried a different browser?

Comment: Tried it one Edge as well, same problem

Comment: When i inspect the page I can clearly see the value attr set to "submit" lol so weird